# React native, call a function inside setInterval when time ==60

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a function, when user click start button that function and timer will start. However, when time reach 60 I want to call stop function but can't figure out how to that. can someone tell me how to do that please.

```js
const [time,setTime] = useState(0)
const timeout = useRef()
const onStart = () => {
  timeout.current = setInterval(() => {
    if (time != 60) {
      setTime(prevState => prevState + 1);
      if (time == 60) {
        onStop()
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}

const onStop = () => {
  clearInterval(timeout.current);
}
```

Comment: Please post useState

Comment: I posted useState with my question

Comment: @DarkPrince My answer should solve the problem for you. Do check the codesandbox.

Comment: ok wait let me it check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to use `time` in your **JSX**, then consider converting it to `ref`. There are certainly closure issues which will take place where the value of `time` state that you expect to be isn't what it will be. Your logic problem of correctly using `if` statements is also covered here.

```
const time = useRef(0)
const timeout = useRef()
const onStart = () => {
  timeout.current = setInterval(() => {
    if (time.current != 60) {
      time.current+=1;
    }
      if (time.current == 60) {
        onStop()
      }
  }, 1000);
}

const onStop = () => {
  clearInterval(timeout.current);
}
```

And in case you need a `state` to be used in **JSX**, just make one `timer` as ref and `time` as state like so :-

```
const timer = useRef(0)
const [time,setTime] = useState(0);
const timeout = useRef()
const onStart = () => {
  timeout.current = setInterval(() => {
    if (timer.current != 60) {
      setTime(prevState => prevState + 1);
      timer.current+=1;
    }
      if (timer.current == 60) {
        onStop()
      }
  }, 1000);
}

const onStop = () => {
  clearInterval(timeout.current);
}
```

See this codesandbox example doing what you want :-

[image: Edit Timer - StackOverflow]

Here is another `React` way which is much less code and confusion :-

```
 const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const timeout = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    onStart();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (time === 60) {
      onStop();
    }
  }, [time]);

  const onStart = () => {
    timeout.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTime((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const onStop = () => {
    clearInterval(timeout.current);
  };
```

[image: Edit Timer-StackOverlow-2]

Comment: @DarkPrince Also check the alternate method. I think that's better for your usecase.

Comment: ya sure I will check

Answer (score 0):

You are first checking if time != 60 this means when its 60 it will not enter in the statement and will not reach the second statement. I think you have to do it like this:

```
timeout.current = setInterval(() => {
   if (time == 60) {
    onStop()
   }
   setTime(prevState => prevState + 1);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: didn't worked, I think the problem is time is not updating inside the function

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it. Your code *will never* stop at 60. As the if statement `if (time != 60)` only runs the code if the time IS NOT 60. Then within that if statement, you've got another if statement going `if time is 60` which it CAN'T be within that if statement as that code is only executed when `time does not equal 60`

Change

```
const [time,setTime] = useState(0)
const timeout = useRef()
const onStart = () => {
    timeout.current = setInterval(() => {
    if (time != 60) {
        setTime(prevState => prevState + 1);
        if (time == 60) {
            onStop()
        }
    }
  }, 1000);
}

const onStop = () => {
  clearInterval(timeout.current);
}
```

to

```
const [time,setTime] = useState(0)
const timeout = useRef()
const onStart = () => {
  timeout.current = setInterval(() => {
    if (time != 60) {
      setTime(prevState => prevState + 1);
    }
    if (time === 60) {
      onStop();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

const onStop = () => {
  clearInterval(timeout.current);
}
```

Comment: console out the time at the beginning of the setInterval function. aka `console.log('Time', time);` before the first `if (time != 60) {` statement and let us know the results. Also...whats your aim here? There's usually ALOT of different choices outside of setInterval/Timeout (which are horrible)